# Compiler Cache Solutions for C# .Net

Tags: .net, performance, tfs, build

We have a large TFS installation with multiple hundred developers working on 500MB of sources. Currently we are using a feature driven approach to development and create a new branch for each feature. You can debate the sanity of this approach but it creates the following situation:

A developer will have multiple branches that are 95% identical. Multiple developers will have the same branches, even the identical version. Only production and integration branches are regularly built, so to do anything useful each developer must build each and every branch they need. Build times take something around 1-2 hours to build everything.

We offset the problem by building the required branches overnight and only building single modules during the actual development. Nevertheless each developer will compile multiple times the exact same assembly, just in a different branch. But occasionally you need to fully build a branch during work.

Are there any "enterprise ready" compiler cache solutions for TFS / Visual Studio? I already used ccache with gcc, but I hardly see how to integrate that into a .Net environment. Googling the issue did not turn up much information, either.

Comment: That's... a lot of code. To address your comment, and (slightly) tongue-in-cheek: "Apparently we have the biggest .Net application ever build. (Apparently "MS said so", but don't know if it is true.)" - go to MS product support, and suggest to them that it might be in their interests from a PR perspective to help you for free on this one...

Comment: Actually for "real" technical issues we have a MS person fix things. But our feature driven approach and the resulting branch structure is root cause of the troubles. At any rate it this would be a senior developer suggesting an improvement. I did my research and though it should be obvious coming from C++... But apparently no one has such large projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build times increase dramatically when you have many projects in a solution. The C# compiler re-analyzes every dll that gets copied, so in a sense the 'copy local' option is evil.

For a possible solution, take a look at [these two articles](https://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx) by [Patrick Smacchia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27194/patrick-from-ndepend-team):

- [Partitioning code base through .NET assemblies and Visual Studio projects](https://www.ndepend.com/Res%5CNDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf)
- [Defining .NET Components with Namespaces](https://www.ndepend.com/Res%5CNDependWhiteBook_Namespace.pdf)

In short, build time increases exponentionally with the number of projects, and because of that, you should try to minimize the number of needed projects, by merging them together. Project/assemblies are often used to force architectural boundries (and I use them like this as well), but this doesn't cut it for large projects. Instead, you can use a tool such as [NDepend](https://ndepend.com) to validate architecture rules, and prevent cyclic dependencies between types. You can do this by grouping types in namespaces and grouping types per feature.

One note though. I've used the advice on the [Partitioning code base through assemblies](https://www.ndepend.com/Res%5CNDependWhiteBook_Assembly.pdf) in one of my open source projects, [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org). Projects don't reference other projects directly, but only assemblies. Downside of this is that the Visual Studio Go To Reference option (F12) doesn't work anymore, since VS doesn't know anything anymore about the project. Instead of jumping to the code, VS will jump to a generated file that only contains the API definition of a type. After consulting Patrick Smacchia about this, he explained that he never experienced this, possible because his team uses Resharper, which seems to still knows how to jump to the code.

Conclusion is that you need to experiment with this, and might want to give all developers a productivity tool such as Resharper, that allows you to still 'jump to code'. And you need a tool such as NDepend (NDepend is great) and integrate it in the build process to ensure that developers don't break architecture rules.

Another option to reduce compile time is to split the teams in such way that core libraries teams become 'external'. Those teams can develop, version, and release there reusable library as DLL that other teams can include in their solution (and checkin that specific version into source control). This saves those teams (probably product teams) from having to compile the base libraries and because those DLLs are (within the solution) placed in one folder, you immediately gain the performance boost as described in Pattrick's article. This has possitive impact on compile time on both the dev box and the build server.

Downside of this approach is that you (again) can't 'jump into' that code, and the process of developing the core libraries will be  much more strict. Those libraries become reusable frameworks and you can't easily change the public API of those libraries. Product/Feature developers also can't simply add/change code or fix bugs in the core library and they need to wait for the Core Team to publish a new release. However, with the current size of your organization (multiple hundreds of devs), you probably already need (or have) a structure like this.

Comment: Interesting insight into the topic. But unfortunately not very useful in this special instance. The code layout is mandated by the architecture of the entire software. Apparently we have the biggest .Net application ever build. (Apparently "MS said so", but don't know if it is true.)

Comment: The software is already relatively well isolated with delayed loading and such. And copying entire components should still break down compile time, not? Well that are pains when you build software that is released on two DVDs...

Comment: Actually the team is split up in base framework and three product teams. If you add about a dozen optional packages and run-time software you end up with almost two dozen teams. I think the big mistake is that the approach was taken to put everything into one big instance of TFS. This results in developers builds software that they never will touch.